# What are the ethical issues with using analytics in Mobile Applications?

Tags: android, iphone, analytics

I would like to implement Google Analytics in my iPad application.

I am wondering if there are any approval process issues with this?

Is there a best practice for allowing users to disable or enable tracking?

Do you have any opinions about how ethical it is to track user app habits?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions that have a definitive answer.  If you want to ask for opinions, you should minimally mark it as community wiki.

Comment: The "best practices" portion of the question seems quite reasonable, since this decision must be made during the design of many types of apps.  The "opinon" (sic) portion is probably inappropriate for here.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [app store approval guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 17 - Privacy
>
> *
>         17.1
>
> Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user''s prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used
>
> *
>         17.2
>
> Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>
> *
>         17.3
>
> Apps that target minors for data collection will be rejected

Comment: What kind of "data about a user" that Apple considers ground for rejection isn't completely clear (excepting 17.2), given that the Wall Street Journal recently reported that 68% of a sample of apps from the App store "phone home" the user's device ID (UDID), most without explicitly asking permission.  Apple's own app EULA seems to state that the user implicitly agrees (but IANAL).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are in BETA, and transmitting information like that is a part of the testing process, you should inform the user for a single and obvious reason:

> You wouldn't be tracked down yourself without being notified by the vendor

If I notice than an application is collecting data about my usage without informing me, I uninstall it immediately.

However, when I'm asked for the permission, sometimes (depending on the application), I kindly accept because I know it will helps developers to do it better.

Answer (score 0):

After hearing your opinions and looking at the pertinent license agreements, this is my answer to the question.

Analytics should not be used transparently. Tracking users, without their knowledge, even if there is no "user identifiable data" is bad.

Per Apple's License Agreement, and also Google Analytics' user agreement, you must notify users that their usage is being tracked and how that information will be used.

[Apple's Agreement on Apple Insider](http://www.appleinsider.com/print/10/09/09/apples_app_store_review_guidelines_we_dont_need_anymore_fart_apps.html)

[Google's Agreement](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/) Thanks coneybeare

Basically that means you have to present an agreement upon the first launch of the app, or have an opt-in option in the application settings. Neither is ideal. Its always a little annoying to get that license agreement popup, it doesn't seem clean to me. But hey, you've got to protect your butt. And not many people would probably agree to opt-in.

It all comes down to carefully balancing user experience with the ability to get insight into your app's usage.